# Front-end dev with Flutter roadmap

Tags: flutter

I just started learning Dart and I'm going to use Flutter for the front-end.
I have some doubts about this road...

Does Flutter cover all needs of a front end for a beginner? Or do I need to learn Sth else too?

Do I need to learn Html and CSS or just Flutter will be OK? How much Html&SSS is needed?

Comment: Flutter is ok. In case you want to work on flutter web, you can learn CSS for more advance usages. For beginners, flutter itself should be enough.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're a beginner in programming in general Flutter may not be the best choice even though I love it. Front end dev is very vague right, what kind of front end are you interested in?

- Web? Go with React, Vue, Angular
- App Cross Platform? React Native, Flutter
- Native app? iOS Swift, Android Kotlin

You don't need to learn html/css for flutter but you do for react, vue, angular, react native. Everything in flutter is done in widgets and those widgets contain design parameters that in my opinion is better than css because the parameters are there and you don't have to google/memorize things.

Flutter does not cover all needs for a front end dev but it does cover one type of front end dev. You can learn just Flutter and build Flutter apps without learning other things first but you'll just be a Flutter Front End Dev, a very specific niche, nothing wrong with that but Flutter isn't as transferable to React Native because the language and framework are completely different. However for web, Flutter still has ways to go, React would be a better approach for web because in Flutter it really feels like an app that's just been packages for web, doesn't really feel natural. But it is amazing for building cross platform apps, built a few and will choose to build apps with Flutter rather than React-Native but for web React is the way to go!